# SQL Server : set a default value for Insert Into query when parameter is null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, ibatis

I'm trying to do an insert query like follow:

```
Insert Into table1 (column1, column2)
Values (#value1#, #value2#)
```

But let's say, I want to default column2 to `2/19/2013` when the parameter `#value2#` is null. How would I achieve that?

I'm using Ibatis framework, and the insert statement is in a XML file, which is used in a db file that is called from the controller.

Comment: you want query in sql, right? what is data type for column2?

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you're looking for:

`ISNULL(#value2#,'2/19/2013')`

Comment: probably want to use `GETDATE()` in place of string literal: `'2/19/2013'`, since today is `2/19/2013`

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change insert statements which are coming from an XML file, you might consider creating a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER table1_Insert ON table1
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, column2)
    SELECT column1, ISNULL(column2,'2/19/2013') FROM INSERTED;
```

Then if try to insert a `NULL`

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, NULL);
```

You'll have

```
| COLUMN1 |   COLUMN2 |
-----------------------
|       1 | 2/19/2013 |
```

Here is **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34226/1)**

Comment: probably want to use `GETDATE()` in place of string literal: `'2/19/2013'`, since today is `2/19/2013`

Comment: Absolutely if the intent is to put the current date and not some base date or something else.